# Android Rooted how to run ASL(Android screenshot library) without running service(run.bat) from PC?

Tags: android, root

I am wondering to develop an app which is having the same functionality of ASL(Android Screen Shot Library ).To run the ASL first we need to invoke the service from our Adb . I want to avoid that and also instead of that i want to keep the ASL-native file in the mobile itself. as well as want to invoke the service from our app . How to do it ??

**Note:** I am trying on rooted mobile support alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is rooted, then avoid use of ASL just make a service which can read framebuffer of device and make a image(png or jpg) file from it. Just look at the code of [**ASL**](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) and [**fb2png**](http://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/) how they read framebuffer and convert it to image.

Also [**ddmlib**](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/android4maven/wiki/ddmlib) help you, it is a library used by **Android DDMS** for image capture functionality.

**EDIT:**

On Rooted Device

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /dev/graphics/fb0");
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
```

And also in manifest file give permission:  `READ_FRAMEBUFFER`

Comment: hi @user370305  i need to take the images with the every second .. for this conditions it will work ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said make a service which runs in background and take a image continuesly.

Comment: Thanks. i will give a try on this and get back to you.

Comment: hi  http://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/, in this link they are explained like how to use it for device .. but for that also they have used adb shell commands know ... how can i use those commands in my app ??? (i mean inside my activity)

Comment: This is not a easy way as you thought, Just use code for how they read frame buffer and converted to image. other-things you have to implemented by your self. Links are for your reference.

Comment: hi, i have tried those device commands my self in android code . adb push fb2png /data/local/ this command worked and have moved the file to the exact place . but i am unable to give the read and write permission for that .... how can i give that ...

Comment: hi @ user370305  i have tried to write inputstream to image file but its not providing valid image file it shows black .. so can u advice me ?

Comment: Actually, its basic image you have to convert it in 32bit dpi.. Look at some code for conversion to 32bit picture..